# Not able to use print statement after using subprocess

Tags: python

I'm using zbarcam to read barcodes, since zbarcam doesn't terminate automatically after reading a code.

Here's my parking-mng.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import MySQLdb as db
from config import *
import sys

temp = ''

def scanfun():
    subprocess.call("./k.sh")
    reg = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    con = None

    con = mdb.connect(server, user, pwd, database);
    cur = con.cursor()
    print "successful"  

while(1):
    print "------Parking Sector 11----------"
    print "Select : "
    print """1. Scan Code\n2. Update Balance\n3. Exit\n"""

    choice = raw_input()

    if choice == '1':
        scanfun()

    else:
        break
```

Here's my k.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmp=/tmp/barcode.$$
zbarcam --raw /dev/video1 > $tmp &
pid=$!

# Sleep until file has content

while [[ ! -s $tmp ]] ; do
    sleep 1
done

kill $pid
cat $tmp | ./parking-mng.py
```

The problem is that the print statement is not working, nothing is getting printed on the terminal.

Comment: your script is probably waiting on the readline() because there is no `\n` on stdin.

Comment: @Chronial No it's not because I'm able to update the database after the print statement, its probably printing somewhere else than terminal. I don't know why

Comment: @Chronial Also after `scanfun()` ends the while loop enters again and `print "------Parking Sector 11----------"` is being displayed, only what is inside the scanfun() is not being displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your `k.sh` runs `parking-mng.py`, which then runs `k.sh`, which then runs `parking-mng.py`, which then runs `k.sh`, which then runs `parking-mng.py`, which then runs `k.sh`, which then runs `parking-mng.py`, which then runs `k.sh`, which then runs `parking-mng.py`, which then runs `k.sh`, which then runs `parking-mng.py`, which then runs `k.sh`, which then runs `parking-mng.py`, which then runs `k.sh`, which then runs `parking-mng.py`, which then runs `k.sh`, which then runs `parking-mng.py`, which then runs `k.sh`, which then runs `parking-mng.py`, which then runs `k.sh`, which then runs `parking-mng.py`, which then runs `k.sh`, which then runs `parking-mng.py`, which then runs `k.sh`, which then runs `parking-mng.py`, which then runs `k.sh`, which then runs `parking-mng.py`, which then runs `k.sh`, which then runs `parking-mng.py`, which then runs `k.sh`, which then runs `parking-mng.py`, which then runs `k.sh`, which then runs `parking-mng.py`, which then runs `k.sh`, which then runs `parking-mng.py`, ...

Infinite recursion much?

Comment: I guess I never pondered over this! :)